# Access Denied on Red Hat (Amazon EC2)

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, redhat

I have set up both `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` to contain the public key of the private key I intend to use. This has already worked with an Ubuntu instance, but with the `ubuntu` user.

The issue is, whether I SSH to this instance's public DNS address and use `root` or `ec2-user` as the user in PuTTy, I get

```
Access denied
ec2-user@ec2-54-213-118-179.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com's password:
```

And a prompt for my password.

This all worked with my Ubuntu instance, but doesn't seem to work with my Red Hat instance.

How do I get Red Hat to properly accept my private key and not prompt me for a password?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding your private key to your running `Pageant` which is basically the ssh agent that does the handshake for Putty ssh sessions.

There's an example on how to use `Pageant` in the WinSCP page:

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pageant

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's related to this bug:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=475492#

If you are using EBS can you try mounting the EBS volume on another instance and examine the problem?

Comment: I have been mounting it on a different volume, specifically for modifying the contents and permissions of `authorized_key`, but no matter what, I was getting the error as I'm describing in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Does the authorized_keys file have 600 permissions?

chmod 600 /home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys

Does the .ssh directory have 700 permissions?

chmod 700 /home/ec2-user/.ssh/

What does the file /var/log/secure say?  That file will usually explain why a SSH login failed.

Comment: They were 400 and 500 respectively.